# Рандомный выбор цвета блока из списка возможных

Tags: css, веб-программирование, веб-дизайн, цвета

Ребят, помогите решить такую задачу.

Есть блок. Допустим, кнопка. К ней привязан стиль.
И есть три цвета, допустим #ff0033, #ff9933 и #33cc33. Как рандомно применять цвет к этой кнопке из списка 3 цветов? Чтобы при перезагрузке кнопка меняла свой цвет на один из трех.
Возможно ли такое вообще сделать средствами css?